# Find Change Tracking Time in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to find the time of changes or transactions  in CT (Change Tracking)
in SQL Server?

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462(v=sql.105).aspx) suggests not, but if you can explain why you need this information then someone may have another solution.

Answer (score 23):

Join `sys.dm_tran_commit_table` for the time.

```
select tc.commit_time, ....
from
    changetable(changes <table>, 0) c
    join sys.dm_tran_commit_table tc on c.sys_change_version = tc.commit_ts
```

Comment: Just a quick note on this (at least in my environment), the time returned from dm_tran_commit_table is UTC + 0.